# Why can't I use three if-statements instead of one if-statement and two elif-statements?

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm struggling to understand the use of `elif` in a specific piece of code https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/markov-chains-python-tutorial.

In the copy-pasted code below, once entering the `while` loop, there is one `if` statement (entered if `activityToday == "Sleep"`) and two `elif` statements (entered if `activityToday == "Run"` or `activityToday == "Icecream"` respectively).

If I run the code, I get the expected output:

```
Start state: Run
Possible states: ['Run', 'Icecream', 'Run']
End state after 2 days: Run
Probability of the possible sequence of states: 0.21
```

If I change the two `elif` statements to two `if` statements, I get some unexpected output:

```
Start state: Run
Possible states: ['Run', 'Run', 'Run']
End state after 2 days: Run
Probability of the possible sequence of states: 0.25
```

The problem is that I don't understand the unexpected output. **I don't understand why I can't replace the two `elif` statements with two `if` statments, and run them as three separate loops instead of one loop with one `if` and two `elif`.** Could someone please explain it to me?

Thanks for any help!

```
import numpy as np
import random as rm

# The statespace
states = ["Sleep","Icecream","Run"]

# Possible sequences of events
transitionName = [["SS","SR","SI"],["RS","RR","RI"],["IS","IR","II"]]

# Probabilities matrix (transition matrix)
transitionMatrix = [[0.2,0.6,0.2],[0.1,0.6,0.3],[0.2,0.7,0.1]]

# FROM THE TUTORIAL 

# A function that implements the Markov model to forecast the state/mood.
def activity_forecast(days):
    # Choose the starting state
    activityToday = "Run"
    print("Start state: " + activityToday)
    # Shall store the sequence of states taken. So, this only has the starting state for now.
    activityList = [activityToday]
    i = 0
    # To calculate the probability of the activityList
    prob = 1
    while i != days:
        if activityToday == "Sleep":
            change = np.random.choice(transitionName[0],replace=True,p=transitionMatrix[0])
            if change == "SS":
                prob = prob * 0.2
                activityList.append("Sleep")
                pass
            elif change == "SR":
                prob = prob * 0.6
                activityToday = "Run"
                activityList.append("Run")
            else:
                prob = prob * 0.2
                activityToday = "Icecream"
                activityList.append("Icecream")
        elif activityToday == "Run":                            # WHY CAN'T I CHANGE 'ELIF' TO 'IF' ??????
            change = np.random.choice(transitionName[1],replace=True,p=transitionMatrix[1])
            if change == "RR":
                prob = prob * 0.5
                activityList.append("Run")
                pass
            elif change == "RS":
                prob = prob * 0.2
                activityToday = "Sleep"
                activityList.append("Sleep")
            else:
                prob = prob * 0.3
                activityToday = "Icecream"
                activityList.append("Icecream")
        elif activityToday == "Icecream":                        # WHY CAN'T I CHANGE 'ELIF' TO 'IF' ??????
            change = np.random.choice(transitionName[2],replace=True,p=transitionMatrix[2])
            if change == "II":
                prob = prob * 0.1
                activityList.append("Icecream")
                pass
            elif change == "IS":
                prob = prob * 0.2
                activityToday = "Sleep"
                activityList.append("Sleep")
            else:
                prob = prob * 0.7
                activityToday = "Run"
                activityList.append("Run")
        i += 1  
    print("Possible states: " + str(activityList))
    print("End state after "+ str(days) + " days: " + activityToday)
    print("Probability of the possible sequence of states: " + str(prob))

# Function that forecasts the possible state for the next 2 days
activity_forecast(2)
```

Comment: If `if` is same as `elif`, why do you think there is a need of `elif`? `elif` is `else` + `if`.

Comment: you are changing `activityToday` value (which is the condition) inside of each branch of the if. So in one loop iteration it might get change multiple times.

`
x = 1
if x == 1:
  x = 2
if x == 2:
  x = 3
`

is not the same as

`
x = 1
if x == 1:
  x = 2
elif x == 2:
  x = 3
`

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this because you change the value of `activityToday` within the `if`/`elif` statements. So, without `elif`, two of the conditional blocks can run within one iteration of the `while` loop.